# Trying to dynamically change "active" class in nav-bar - Node.js/Express/Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, navbar

I am having a slight issue in trying to get the "active" class set when I click on the link so that I know which page I am in. Currently what happens is when I click on a different tab it sets it "active" but then goes away when the page is loaded.

I am using Node.js, Express, Handlebar and Bootstrap. I have a feeling it has to do something with the fact that the class="nav-link active" is in the < a > tag instead of the < li > tag?

Please also find a quick video of the issue described:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ8hU.jpg

thanks in advance!

layout.handlebars

```
<div class="container">
  <div  class="header clearfix">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home App</a>
       <ul id="navbarMenu" class="nav nav-pills">
                  {{#if user}}
         <li id="dashboardNav" class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link active" href="/">Dashboard</a>
         </li>
         <li id="accountNav" class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/users/account">Account</a>
         </li>
         <li id="logoutNav" class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
         </li>
                    {{else}}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/users/login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/users/register">Register</a>
        </li>
            {{/if}}
       </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('ul.nav-pills li').on("click", "a", function() {
        alert("test");
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("nav-link active");
      $(this).addClass("nav-link active");

      //alert($this.child().href);
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the view (handlebars) add if condition:

```
  <a class="nav-link {{#if path "foo"}} active {{/if}}" href="/foo">Dashboard</a>
```

In the server side (route or controller that render the view) Edit it and pass the path variable:

```
router.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('foo', { title: 'foo' ,path:"foo",});
});
```

Do that for each page you want to add active css class for each anchor.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to actually do it on the server side using handlebars {{#if}} block statements and passing the handlebars the appropriate variable from the routes.

Comment: Whats the solution?